# Redirect from domain 1 to domain 2 without http code 301 or 302

Tags: apache

I need to set an apache rule in order to redirect all the traffic from a domain 1 to a domain 2.
The particularity of the request is that there must be only one call to the second domain with http code 200 and not two calls (one with 301/302 to the first domain and the second with 200 to the second domain).
Pratically, for the client the redirect must be transparent.

Is it possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to avoid a redirection is to have 'domain 1' set up as a proxy to 'domain 2'.

Comment: Hello Umar,
can you give me help to configure the proxy? A link, a guide? The domain 1 is my apache in localhost, while the domain 2 is on another server. I can make configuration only on my apache.

Comment: Hope this helps-http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html